# Reading JSON response from Silex REST API

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony, silex

I have some javascript that used to call a PHP file to get a list of countries, using jquery.

The PHP returned a json encoded array that looked like this:

[
    {
        "CountryID": "11",
        "CountryName": "Argentina"
    },
    {
        "CountryID": "14",
        "CountryName": "Australia"
    },
    {
        "CountryID": "15",
        "CountryName": "Austria"
    },
    {
        "CountryID": "20",
        "CountryName": "Barbados"
    },
etc

My javascript read this OK and popped all the names into a list, like this:

var queryString = "api/countries.php";

```
$.get(queryString, function(data){

    var obj = JSON.parse(data); 
    var thisGet = obj.length;
    var countryList = document.getElementById('country_list');

    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    for (i = 0; i < thisGet; i++)
    {
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = obj[i].CountryID;
        opt.innerHTML = obj[i].CountryName;
        countryList.appendChild(opt);
    }
});
```

This worked fine, but I started using Silex (Symfony) for something else, so I created a route to get my countries. This works fine when you just type the URL into a browser or Postman, but it has to return a Response. This is the new code:

```
$app->get('/usedcountries', function() use($app) { 

    $result = getCountries();
    $response = new JsonResponse();
    $response->setData($result);
    return $response;
});
```

When my javascript gets the data now, it can't read it, and if I display it in an alert, I just get this:

[object Object],[object Object],... etc

Can anyone please explain what I need to do to get the data from the Response? I've looked at all the other questions on here that SO recommended, but none of them help.

(getCountries just does a call into a database, like this:

```
function getCountries() {
    global $DBH;

    $q = 'SELECT * FROM country_summary ORDER BY CountryName';
    $stmt = $DBH->prepare($q);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
    return $rows;
}
```

TIA.

Comment: Don't use `alert` for development. `alert` converts the value to a **string**. Use `console.log` instead or set breakpoints.

Comment: Perhaps you can point me to the part of that post (which I have read twice now) that answers my question?

Comment: It looks like what you have should just work. The fact that you get that output means that you are receiving an array of objects. You might want to use `console.log` to verify the structure of the array.

Comment: Thanks.

It seems that I don't need to do this with the JsonResponse:

var obj = JSON.parse(data);

as the data is already in the right format.

Also, I couldn't get it working without a root node, but when I added one I could access all the members from that.
So, I now have this:

    for (i = 0; i < data.countries.length; i++)
    {
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = data.countries[i].CountryID;
        opt.innerHTML = data.countries[i].CountryName;
        countryList.appendChild(opt);
    }

Comment: Well, you should only use `console.log` for debugging your code, not use it in production. And yes, with the right headers, jQuery will parse the JSON automatically for you. I guess `JsonResponse` sets the right headers. You should have seen an error in the console actually.

Comment: Ooop, I forgot you can't format code in a reply :(

Thanks for your help.